# Use and load extensions ("plugins") for Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Just started using Sencha Touch 2 and need to integrate the Leaflet plugin https://github.com/VinylFox/Ext.ux.touch.Leaflet/tree/master/src.

I've just started using Sencha, and wasn't able to find in the documentation where to drop in and reference such extensions. What's the file structure and reference code necessary to do so? Does it just go anywhere and I reference it in app.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sencha documentation isn't very explicit, but someone was able to shed some light on Ext.Loader and how it fits into the bigger picture.

Taking the Leaflet extension above, the `Ext.Loader` is basically the tool to load what someone might call a "plugin" in layman terms.

http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-ext-loader-for-your-application/

So in `app.js` you can use `Ext.Loader` to load the plugin via:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths   : {
        'Ext.Leaflet': './Ext.ux.touch.Leaflet/Ext.ux.touch.Leaflet.js'
    }
});
Ext.require('Ext.Leaflet');
```

Comment: Found this by typing 'loader' into the search in docs:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-2/#!/api/Ext.Loader

The examples are very informative... not sure what else you need.